# Decorate an ear with custom implementation

Tags: maven

We have an ear built by Maven, lets call it core product. We would like to pull this core product ear (say as dependency) and replace few class files with implementation that is custom to a specific product. Does Maven allow to do such a thing?

Comment: Sure you can explode it and repackage with altered files it but it would seem smarter to package a version with the files you need in the first place.

Comment: Do we have a plugin that would explode and repackage it? Do you think maven-dependency-plugin could do this trick? I definitely don't want to do this manually, it has to be as part of the build. May be a separate build that would pull the core dependency, explode it and repackage it.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me answer my own question for those who stumble on similar requirement.

```
product-core
          + -- pom.xml
          + -- EarBuilderModule
          + -- JarBuilderModule
                            + -- jar-a
                            + -- jar-b
```

Lets assume we would want to create a new ear for a client "someClient" with custom implementation in jar-a. Lets say custom implementation requires an update to existing class and addition of few new classes and packages.

```
product-someClient
          + -- pom.xml
          + -- EarBuilderModule
          + -- JarBuilderModule
                           + -- jar-a
```

> **Solution:** place the new files in src/main/java in jar-a, configuration files that needs to be updated in src/main/resources and
>   so on. Nothing fancy here as this is default Maven conventions. For
>   ease of typing and understanding let me call product-core as A and
>   product-someclient as B. Update jar-a in A to build source for for it
>   using maven-source-plugin. Would not provide details on how to use
>   maven-source-plugin as its available online is straight copy paste
>   job. Once you have built and installed A source in local repository
>   you would make the following updates to jar-a in project B.

```
     <groupId>com.mycompany.someclient.base</groupId>
     <artifactId>jar-a</artifactId>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-shared-resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                  <groupId>com.mycompany.core.base</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>jar-a</artifactId>
                                   <classifier>sources</classifier>
                                   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                   <type>jar</type>
                                   <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                                   <includes>**/*.java,**/*.properties</includes>
                                   <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>false</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Next thing is update to pom.xml in EarBuilderModule to use jar-a from com.mycompany.someclient.base instead of com.mycompany.core.base.

Hope this post helps other in need and if required you could always reach out to me for additional help.